# Youtube API for now watching video with playback position?

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

### What I need

For a personal automation idea, I need a way (any way) to programmatically get the Youtube video with playback position that I'm now watching on iOS. Either via REST API, or via Youtube's iOS app somehow (I'm close to desperate).

I'm guessing a direct iOS way, if possible, would be preferable, because it will work offline.

### What I researched

- There doesn't seem to be a direct API like there is on Spotify
- The Watch History API has been removed a few years ago
- I searched the iOS shortcuts app for a Youtube connector, but there is none
- Google My Activity would indeed list the videos I watched, but it doesn't have any API either, and it seems it doesn't have the current playback timestamp anyway, only the fact that I watched a given video
- The closest I found was using Google Takeout to request the account data, but it's not real-time

Is there maybe a connector that's available for e.g a native iOS Swift app? Or what are my options, if I have any?

Comment: Haven't tried yet, but, if you enter to [Google My Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?pli=1), you'll see the videos you watched, then, you should try to scrap the webpage or download it and check the HTML; I did this once with another page and in C#, but, I don't know how you could try this approach - I don't know about ios...the playback time (*I think*) is already calculated before shown in the Google My Activity. See this [screenshot I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ATSI.png) for details.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Hi Marco, thank you for the tip, it looks promising, will look into it and get back to you!